# Address Can't be Empty inside Whole Field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below screenshot,
User have to Add Address but If they enter Space bar 4-5 time then this input type assume it a value & then addres submit button Proceed,

```
<div className={AddressBox} style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                
              </div>
<button className="submit_Button" type="button" onClick={() => submit()}><span>Submit</span></button>
```

But If I apply **.trim()** inside value option i.e.. **value={form.address_1.trim()}** then I don't have any option to give space between the address.

Guide me in this.

On Submit Button, I put this below condition

```
if (!address.length) {
    alert( 'Enter Your Address' );
    return;
  }
```

**Requirement:-**  If I enter multiple space inside Input type="text" box then form is not submitted.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trim` on `onBlur` to remove sapce when click outside the input:

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
value={form.address}
onBlur={(e) => handleChange({ target: { value: e.target.value.trim() } })}
```

Comment: If I use trim() then In the whole Address field, there is no option to give space between two word.

Comment: Use trim in `onBlur` will can do it

Comment: Space removed but even I can't put space between two words

Comment: Please copy my code. Only use trim in the `onBlur`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a flag to specify if the form can be submitted.

Something like (*simplified version*)

```
const canSubmitForm = form.address.trim() !== '';
```

and then on the button set the `disable` attribute accordingly

```
<button 
  className="submit_Button" 
  type="button" 
  onClick={() => submit()}
  disabled={!canSubmitButton}
  >
  <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

---

The test above is very simple, you should create a validation for the whole form